# Некорректная работа обобщенного метода

Tags: c#, async-await, методы, singleton

Всем привет.
Есть некий интерфейс `IChatAttributes` от которого наследуются некие классы (`AiAttributes`, `NavAttributes`, `ContentAttributes`.. - данные классы создаются с помощью паттерна Синглтон). Также есть класс `ChatAttributes` который в конструкторе создает инстансы наследников и кладет их в свое единственное свойство `List<IChatAttributes> AttributesList`
Необходимо написать обобщенный метод, который будет доставать из `AttributesList` 
объекты классов наследников и возвращать их.

Я сделал так:

```
public  T  GetCurrentAttribute<T>()
{
    T returnedObject = default(T);

    foreach (var item in AttributesList)
    {
        if (item is T) returnedObject = (T)item;
        else returnedObject = default(T);
    }

    return returnedObject;
}
```

Теперь моделирую ситуацию:

`attributesList` сформировался и содержит два объекта `IChatAttributes` (`AiAttributes` и  `ContentAttributes`). C помощью асинхронного метода в другом классе я хочу извлечь эти объекты посредством вышеуказанного обобщенного метода:

```
 var aiObj= await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => attribute.GetCurrentAttribute<AiRoutAttributes>());
 var cntObj= await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => attribute.GetCurrentAttribute<ContentAttributes>());
```

в итоге в `aiObj` данные приходят а в `cntObj` нет.

Где я что упустил, помогите разобраться.

Comment: Вопрос стоял не в том что условный метод отробатывает в обеих ветках, а в необходимости написания корректного обобщенного метода. @Андрей NOP Предложил оптимальный вариант метода без ипользования условной конструкции.

Comment: Ну Pavel Mayorov здесь тоже отчасти прав, ваш код находит нужный вам элемент, но следующая итерация просто перезапишет `returnedObject`, поэтому результат поиска будет утрачен. Ваш код можно починить просто удалив ветку else внутри цикла :) В моем же варианте условная конструкция просто спрятана внутри `OfType`, ну и я просто показал как можно воспользоваться готовыми средствами стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: @РоманТимохов вопрос в его текущей формулировке был в том что у вас не работал метод. Я объяснил почему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша реализация `GetCurrentAttribute` неверна. Просто посмотрите ход выполнения метода под отладчиком, ошибка на поверхности.

А вообще можно же переписать проще, как-то так:

```
return AttributesList.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
// Или SingleOrDefault, если нужно контролировать, что запись такого типа ровно одна
```